# selenium working first for but not second. Element not found in cache - perhaps the page

Tags: python, selenium

I have asked about three question about this script in here. Several errors later I have got so far. I was trying to work my way around this script but I'm stuck at this part and don't know how to fix it.

Basically I would like to see unreaded messages on a website and answer it later. I'm stuck at the part I have a `for loop` checking for every unreaded messages and keeping the `id` of the conversation so I can use it later on the url.

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import re

email = "xxx@gmail.com"
password = "xxxxx"

print "Openning Browser"
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https://olx.pt/account/?ref[0][action]=myaccount&ref[0][method]=index")
print "Logging into OLX"
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("login[email]")
elem.send_keys(email)
elem = browser.find_element_by_name("login[password]")
elem.send_keys(password)
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
print "Loged into OLX"
time.sleep(5)
browser.get("https://olx.pt/myaccount/answers/")

while browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded"):
   print "Unreaded messages!"
   unread_answers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded") 
   for unread_row in unread_answers:
    row_id = unread_row.get_attribute("id")
    m = re.search('answer_row_(\d+)', row_id)
    row_number = m.group(1)
    print row_number
    print "First loop"
    browser.refresh()
    time.sleep(5) 
else:
    print "All read!"
```

Here is the output:

```
Openning Browser
Logging into OLX
Loged into OLX
Unreaded messages!
315911723
First loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "loginolxbackup.py", line 28, in <module>
row_id = unread_row.get_attribute("id")
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 113, in get_attribute
resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 469, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 201, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up
Stacktrace:
at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9407)
at Utils.getElementAt (file:///tmp/tmpvdAiKH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:8992)
at WebElement.getElementAttribute (file:///tmp/tmpvdAiKH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12099)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpvdAiKH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12614)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpvdAiKH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12619)
at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpvdAiKH/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12561)
```

The html page I'm looking at is something like this:

```
<tr id="answer_row_3121238" class="bla bla bla">
...
<tr id="answer_row_3121428" class="bla bla bla">
...
<tr id="answer_row_3124238" class="bla bla bla">
```

I have tried printing out `m` and I saw it has 3 objects wich mean it's fetching all of the unreaded messages.

I'm banging my head against the wall without any luck. Any advice/help would be much apreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `browser.refresh()` the DOM is rendered and the WebDriver is loosing all the elements it previously located, and that what causing the exception. It even in the stack trace: ***perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up***.

Either avoid refreshing the page (I don't see here any need for it) or relocate all the messages every iteration of the `for` loop.

Example for relocation every iteration

```
unread_answers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded")
messages_len = len(unread_answers)
for x in range(0, messages_len - 1):
    unread_answers = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("tr.unreaded")
    row_id = unread_answers[x].get_attribute("id")
    m = re.search('answer_row_(\d+)', row_id)
    row_number = m.group(1)
    print row_number
    print "First loop"
    browser.refresh()
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "relocate all the messages every iteration of the `for` loop"?

Comment: @JohnMeter I added an example.

Comment: I'm getting the same error I was getting. Could you land me a hand? It makes the first loop. It gives me the number of the unreaded message. Then it `Attribute error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'` at `row_number = m.group(1)`.

Comment: @JohnMeter It looks like another error, `re.search('answer_row_(\d+)', row_id)` returns `None`. I don't know what is `re.search()`.